# error when writing an app from a tutorial

Tags: python, django

Good day!

I create an application on django based on the tutorial from the official documentation, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python372\Lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\python372\Lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\django\JustProject\JustProject\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', include('Project.urls'), ),
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\django\JustProject\Project\urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    url('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView(), name='results'),
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 13, in url
    return re_path(regex, view, kwargs, name)
  File "C:\virtualenv\hello\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

I'm trying to figure it out myself, but so far it's not working out well. Perhaps someone can tell you?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Question, Choice

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.object.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'detail.html'

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {
            'question':question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

urls.py - App

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings


app_name = 'project'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

In General, I only need to point out the error, then I hope I can handle it myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the error message: `TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`
It's coming from this line:

`File "c:\django\JustProject\Project\urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    url('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView(), name='results'),`

`ResultsView()` is a class which is not callable.

You missed the `.as_view()` in:

```py
path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView(), name='results'),
```